# How can I prevent a GameObject within a ScrollView from moving?

Tags: unity, gui, scrolling

I have a ScrollView.  It has children, most of which I want to scroll, but some of which I want to remain still.  Think of something along the lines of a spreadsheet where the title rows/columns don't move.

I have somewhat succeeded, as the GameObjects I want to stay in their place do, but they are fighting the ScrollView to move.  It forces them to jitter every time I scroll.  Here is my current code:

```
private Vector3 originalPosition = Vector3.zero;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => transform.position == Vector3.zero);
    originalPosition = transform.position;
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    if (originalPosition == Vector3.zero)
    {
        return;
    }
    transform.position = originalPosition;
}
```

What is causing it to jitter?  And how can I fix it?

(The reason I am waiting to start updating is because my GameObject originally thinks its position is (0, 0, 0)...not sure why.  Maybe its related?)